# MongoDB Exact Match with Conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've created this collection of URIs and a function that lets me pass the URI and httpMethod, which builds a MongoDB query to find the matching document. The catch is that the URIs can have dynamic elements in them...  like so :

```
/api/v1/users/{userid}/profile
```

But there can also be URIs like this :

```
/api/vi/users/all/
```

I blocked out my URIs in the collect, so I wrote this Mongo Query :

```
db.apis.aggregate({
    "$match" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {"$or" : [{"_uri_.blocks.block" : "api","_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 1.0}},{"_uri_.blocks.isWild" : true,"_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 1.0}}]}, 
            {"$or" : [{"_uri_.blocks.block" : "v1","_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 2.0}},{"_uri_.blocks.isWild" : true,"_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 2.0}}]}, 
            {"$or" : [{"_uri_.blocks.block" : "users","_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 3.0}},{"_uri_.blocks.isWild" : true,"_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 3.0}}]}, 
            {"$or" : [{"_uri_.blocks.block" : "{userid}","_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 4.0}},{"_uri_.blocks.isWild" : true,"_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 4.0}}]}, 
            {"$or" : [{"_uri_.blocks.block" : "profile","_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 5.0}},{"_uri_.blocks.isWild" : true,"_uri_.blocks.position" : {"$eq" : 5.0}}]}, 
            {"_canonical_._httpMethod_":"POST"}
        ]
    }
},
    {"$limit" : 1.0})
```

But it doesn't seem to do the exact match as I was hoping.

Any suggestions on how I can query Mongo to only return the most accurate document?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to match a pattern, taking the following input :

```
db.apis.insert([{
    "uri": "/api/v1/users/someUser/profile"
}, {
    "uri": "/api/v2/users/otherUser/profile"
}, {
    "uri": "/api/v2/users/otherUser/login"
}, {
    "uri": "/api/v1/users/someUser/login"
}, {
    "uri": "/api/v1/users/all/"
}])
```

- match `/api/v{version}/users/{userId}/profile`

  ```
  var userId = "someUser";
  var version = 1;
  var limit = 1;

  db.apis.find({
      "uri": {
          $regex: '/api/v' + version + '/users/' + userId + '/profile'
      }
  }).limit(limit)
  ```
- match `/api/v{version}/*`

  ```
  var version = 1;
  var limit = 10;

  db.apis.find({
      "uri": {
          $regex: '/api/v' + version + '/.*'
      }
  }).limit(limit)
  ```

Comment: Is there a way, if I add the regex version of the URI in the documents, that I could search my URI from that?

So my document might have this for URI 

/api/v.*/users/.*/profile

and then do something like db.apis.find("uri":"/api/v2/users/12312341/profile")

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do, don't you want to look for a userId matching in a specific url pattern ?

Comment: Well here's my issue..   I'm trying to automate a rather large API network (3500+ different URIs).   So I'll never know which block in the URI is static or dynamic.   

I have a document for each URI in my collection, which contains routing info and what not.

Comment: can you give an example of document input and the expected output you would need in your question ?